# Get photos from stream

Tags: facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

Is there a way to get all of the photos form a given stream query? I tried the following but it returns an empty set.

```
SELECT pid, aid, src_big FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT attachment.media.photo.pid FROM #feed)
```

Comment: And what SELECT attachment.media.photo.pid FROM #feed returns?

Comment: It returns the correct data sort of, but it is nested in 4 empty objects.

Comment: Please, can you add this data to your post?

Comment: @DavidBeck Did you finally find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Its tough to tell since I can't see your '#feed' query but more than likely you are missing a stream_filter query. This would give you something like the following 3 queries. Good Luck!

Query **'key'**:

```
SELECT filter_key
  FROM stream_filter
  WHERE uid = me() AND name = 'Photos'
```

Query **'feed'**:

```
SELECT attachment.media.photo.pid
  FROM stream
  WHERE source_id = {id here} AND filter_key IN (SELECT filter FROM #key)
```

Query **'photos'**:

```
SELECT caption, src_big, modified
    FROM photo
    WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM #feed)
```